# Division by zero error in crosstab formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

My crosstab displays the total hours for each user. The display Column's grand total is formatted as a percentage:

```
Task          |  User1  |  User2  | Etc . . . 
TotalTime        41.68     44.55
TotalHours       52.17     84.93
% Total          79.89%    52.45%
```

I use a formula field `({TotalTime}/{TotalHrs}) * 100` - but when I drag that formula field into *Summarized Field*, I get a `Division by zero` error. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a forumula and write below code.

```
If {TotalHrs}=0
then ToText(0)
Else ToText((({TotalTime}/{TotalHrs}) * 100),2)
```

Now use this forumula in cross tab.

Comment: I also did that formula but the %TOTAL row is all in ZERO value. All I want is to get that 79.89% and 53.45% total. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Edited my answer for that decimal part

Comment: yes it works but the expected result is not 79.89% and 53.45%

Comment: Means? you need "%" symbl as well?

Comment: not necessarily its ok if in decimal or percentage what i mean is they are not the same value display when i integrate that formula i get the value 43 and 84 instead of 79.89 and 53.45

Comment: It has nothing to do with the crystal reports check your data may be it is wrong.

Comment: Actually this report is made in RDLC and it works perfect but my superior demand me to convert it to crystal report but when I convert, it didn't work.

Comment: Check your data and fields formula I have provided is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a numeric formula as well:

```
If Not(Isnull({TotalHrs})) Then ({TotalTime}/{TotalHrs}) * 100
```